# Can JavaScript function outside of the [CDATA[ tag?

Tags: javascript, svg

From what I read, JavaScript within an SVG must be put into a [CDATA[ tag (the type designation is apparently now optional):

```
<script type="application/javascript"> 
<![CDATA[

 (JavaScipt stuff here)

]]> 
</script>
```

However, the following markup/code works without that tag even though it looks like JavaScript methods are being used:

```
<svg width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<rect id="rect1" x="160" y="10" width="60" height="60"  fill="blue"
onmouseenter="evt.target.setAttribute('fill', 'red');"
onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('x', '0');"
/>
</svg>
```

So, are the evt.target.setattribute commands all SVG? I know this is a super newbie question...but I am having a hard time establishing where SVG ends and JavaScript begins. Documentation is very sketchy on the delineation, and I want to learn the total extent of what I can do in SVG before needing to learn another language. Thanks much for any clarification. And if anyone knows of a reference that is very clear on the subject, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

A CDATA section is a feature of XML documents. It's not part of html. You seem to be using SVG in html given that your SVG example has not namespaces so CDATA is neither required nor useful there.

In standalone SVG you need namespaces defined i.e. xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" and there you need CDATA to prevent various characters in javascript e.g. < being interpreted as the beginning of a tag. Other characters are problematic too.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. It may well be my ignorance, but I don't understand how the answer relates to my question. In Chrome, at least, the code runs exactly as posted here so as far as I can tell, since there is no html markup at all, no html is involved(?). My question remains: is the evt.target.setAttribute code part of SVG? Or is it javascript functions that are running despite not being inside the tag structure at the top of my posting? Or is it yet something else that's not so clearly either?

Comment: It's all about the mime type you're using. if the page is text/html it's html whether there's any html markup or not. setAttribute is part of the DOM, it's neither html nor SVG but common to both.